# Is it to be expected that short QStrings will collide with qHash?

Tags: qt, hash

I ran into what seems to be a collision between two `QString` objects with three-character strings:

```
const QString one = "haç";
const QString two = "hek";
qDebug() << one << qHash(one);
qDebug() << two << qHash(two);
```

Here is the output (which I redirected from the console to a file so that the special character would come out correctly):

```
Debug: "haç" 103182
Debug: "hek" 103182
```

I'm accustomed to think of hash collisions as a theoretical possibility rather than something that would happen in practice. Is `qHash` is more likely to produce collisions for short strings?

(I'm getting this behavior in Qt 5.15.1.)

Here is a MWE if anyone else wants to test it:

main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    const QString one = "haç";
    const QString two = "hek";
    qDebug() << one << qHash(one);
    qDebug() << two << qHash(two);

    return a.exec();
}
```

untitled.pro

```
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce it neither with Qt4 nor with Qt5 - I got different hash values.

Comment: That's very strange. I added a MWE. I'm using Qt 5.15.1, MinGW 64-bit.

Comment: Is your source code file (main.cpp) properly encoded (UTF-8)?

Comment: Yep, it's UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code of `qHash`, one could inspect the used algorithm:

```
uint h = seed;

if (seed && hasFastCrc32())
    return crc32(p, len, h);

for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    h = 31 * h + p[i].unicode();

return h;
```

CRC32 is only used when a seed is specified and the cpu supports it. Otherwise a much simpler algorithm is used.

If you specify a seed (like QHash and other Qt classes would do by default), you would obtain a different result, i.e. no collision occurs.

Comment: So I could hardcode a seed, or generate one at runtime? (I'm not expecting hash values to remain constant between different runs of the program.)

Comment: A static seed is fine if you are only concerned about avoiding collisions. Qt uses/recommends a random hash (f.ex. [`qGlobalQHashSeed`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhash.html#qGlobalQHashSeed)) to avoid [algorithm complexity attacks](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhash.html#algorithmic-complexity-attacks).

Comment: Thank you very much. For anyone looking to copy/paste, what I needed was: `qHash(two, static_cast<uint>(qGlobalQHashSeed()) )`